# Duplicate names in sitelinks in google search (Shopify website)

Tags: shopify, e-commerce, liquid

So if you Google "pets go here" or "petsgohere", you will see that the site links under my client's website https://www.petsgohere.com/ 2 of the site links have duplicate names:

"Dog Dog Store" (https://petsgohere.com/pages/dog-store)

"CAT Cat Store" (https://petsgohere.com/pages/cat-store) [image]

What puzzles me is that I don't see duplicate names in the admin area either:

[image]

When I open up my theme.liquid, track down how the `<title>` element, here is how it's rendered:

```
  {% capture seo_title %}
  {{ page_title }}
  {% if current_tags %}
  {%- assign meta_tags = current_tags | join: ', ' %} &ndash; {{ 'general.meta.tags' | t: tags: meta_tags -}}
  {% endif %}
  {% if current_page != 1 %}
  &ndash; {{ 'general.meta.page' | t: page: current_page }}
  {% endif %}
  {% unless page_title contains shop.name %}
  &ndash; {{ shop.name }}
  {% endunless %}
  {% endcapture %}
  <title>{{ seo_title }}</title>
```

**Would anyone out there have any insight on how to resolve this issue or at least know what the issue is?**

**Can anyone break the code down piece by piece?**

Comment: I am not sure but this may help you somehow. This may be due to the fact that you do have the Pages as well as Collections with same name.
like /collections/dog-store and /pages/dog-store.
You may try Fetch as Google in webmaster tools to see more information..

Answer (score 1):

In your theme, you are rendering the  element with Liquid. That is where you will find some code duplicating your title words. Ensure you render just the right data and not some crazy marketing scheme that is clearly not working!

First thing in your seo_title captured is the page_title. As per the documentation: https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/objects/page-title

Then the capture will deal with pages in case of more than 1, and the shop name. You can strip this down to be whatever you want. The Liquid capture element simply collects all things rendered in a giant string. So as per my answer, this pattern was invented long ago, to try and make some auto-sense of things in Shopify, and it is not really SEO special, it is simply a mechanical dump. You can do better depending on how you choose to appear. Remembering that page_title is for HUMANS to read, this pattern is weak at best.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "crazy marketing scheme that is clearly not working". Can you explain exactly what you mean by "crazy marketing scheme" so that I can actually do something about it? Examples, please.  I don't work with my client on a daily bases nor did I develop the theme. I only consult with my client and their marketing scheme is their own.

Comment: Seeing CAT CAT. DOG DOG. Sounds like somebody thought they would be clever by repeating something. Hence my words, crazy marketing scheme. If you are going to ask for technical help here but claim no skills, why? Hire someone to fix this who knows Shopify 101.

Comment: Technical skill I have. You've provided me with zero technical help. Not only did you fail to show me that you investigated the issue, but you've also failed to provide me with example code or a file to investigate. Again a technical example. Not an opinion, please. For example, "in your Chrome browser, go to https://petsgohere.com/pages/cat-store > in developers tools > inspect > sources tab > Pages > cat-store > you will find that ..." or " if you "view the page source in the chrome browser you will find that the element..." negative assumptions without proof = criticism. Not technical help.

Comment: Quit whining. It would take you two seconds to open up theme.liquid, track down how the <title> element is rendered, fix it, and move on.

Comment: It took you an answer & a comment to get there but thank you for actually providing me with technical help. I will update my question.

Comment: is there any way you can break down my code piece by piece by piece?